# Standalone installation of ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, partitioning, backup, ntfs, standalone-session

I have windows 8 installed on my PC and now i want to install ubuntu 13.10 as a standalone OS i.e. i dont want to keep windows 8.

I have 3 partition on my HDD.

1. 350 MB (Boot Files in NTFS)
2. 100 GB (Windows 8 in NTFS)
3. 600 GB (DATA in NTFS)

I dont have backup method to backup my data on 600 GB partition so how do i install ubuntu.
 Can anyone tell in detailed manner and also i want to install it from USB.

Can I access DATA after installation which is in NTFS format.

Answer (score 1):

The installation is pretty simple:

- Remove all partitions that are not the 600Gb.
- Create partitions for / and if you want for /home and if you want for swap.

> Can I access DATA after installation which is in NTFS format.

Yes, all you need to do is mount the disc as shown here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions with the ntfs-3g driver.

It -is- as simple as this.

Comment: I didnt get -"Remove all partitions that are not the 3.6Tb."

Comment: sorry I misread the text @AmitKumarVerma